# Why is the standard error in a diff-in-diff with 4 datapoints 'not well defined'?

Tags: panel-data, standard-error, difference-in-difference, synthetic-data

I was looking at this online book https://matheusfacure.github.io/python-causality-handbook/15-Synthetic-Control.html in order to learn about synthetic control. The author gets two cities in a panel with the target variable being analysed before and after an intervention. At some point, he says "However, note that the sample size here is 4, which is also the number of parameters in our Diff-in-Diff models. In this case, the standard error is not well defined...", what does he mean by NOT WELL DEFINED?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you have more free parameters than you do observations, hence there's no way to estimate their standard error. The model has free-parameters for: baseline, pre/post time, group indicator, the group by time interaction, and the standard error term.

Consider for a normal model, you need just one observation to estimate the mean, two observations for the mean and CI. In a bivariate linear model, you need just three observations to estimate the intercept and slope and CIs. Each parameter subtracts one from the degrees of freedom for the sampling distribution of the residual standard error until, overspecified, there is no distribution by which to compare it to, and consequently: no test.